# Error with pgfornament

Tags: pgfornament

I installed pgfornament in my texlive installation by downloading the package folder and following the manual:

- pgfornament must to be in `/texmf/tex/latex`
- pgflibraryvectorian.code.tex must to be in `/texmf/tex/latex`
- pgflibraryam.code.tex must to be in `/texmf/tex/latex` the folder
- vectorian must to be in `/texmf/tex/generic` the folder am must to be
  in `/texmf/tex/generic`

but when I try to compile a mwe like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17.4cm,paperheight=11.4cm,textwidth=15cm,top=1.2cm,bottom=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{ornament}

\begin{document}
\pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = red]{1}

hello world

\end{document}
```

it gives me the error : `File 'ornament.sty' not found`. How can I solve this? If it helps I am using lualatex as engine.

Comment: Should it not be `\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}`?

Comment: Wow! Thank you. It's strange the manual says ornament but you are correct. Make it an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Yes it was a mistake in the documentation but just as you wrote: `pgfornament must to be in /texmf/tex/latex` le package est bien `pgfornament`.

Comment: @AlainMatthes thank you for the clarification. By the way, I love your tkz-euclide package.

Comment: @Emmet thanks !! I work actually on the pgfornament package.  I still need a few more days to finish the documentation. The next version of ` tkz-euclide` is ready (3.06) but I need to learn Git before downloading the package. And I'm preparing a version of `tkz-euclide` called `elements` that will only do geometry without `tkz-base` with the same macros.

Comment: @Emmet  I made a big update of the package and the documentation thanks to your question ! thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation uses `\usepackage{ornament}` and talks about the "ornaments package"... Well, I believe the package is still under construction. Don't know. You might want to give the author a short message on this post here as it is confusing as it stands now.

At the moment, the package seems to be named `pgfornament` and should therefore be used like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17.4cm,paperheight=11.4cm,textwidth=15cm,top=1.2cm,bottom=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
\pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = red]{1}

hello world

\end{document}
```